# R Shiny Error with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, bar-chart

I trying to develop a simple Shiny APP to display a bar chart. In the example I'm following (https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/telephones-by-region.html) the plot is Phone by Region. I want simpler: just a count by candidate (my data: dados).

The main problem is with the `input` command inside the bar plot code. The original

```
barplot(WorldPhones[,input$region]*1000, 
        main=input$region,
        ylab="Number of Telephones",
        xlab="Year")
```

should be substituted by

```
ggplot(data=dados, aes(x=dados[input$candidato])) +
  geom_bar(stat="count")
```

Doing this, I got the error:

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type
>   tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous. Warning: Error in :
>   Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Data sample:

Candidato1 Candidato2 Candidato3

```
      <chr>             <chr>             <chr>
```

POSITIVO          NEGATIVO          POSITIVO          POSITIVO
NEGATIVO          POSITIVO          NEGATIVO          NEGATIVO
POSITIVO          POSITIVO          NEGATIVO          NEGATIVO

How can I solve this? Appears that ggplot can't accept my string, but outside shiny, works fine.

Tks, Ricardo.

Comment: You should explain where from `input$candidato` came? What do You wanna do with it? Is it column name or values in column? If `input$candidato` represents the filter values in a column, what is the column name?

Comment: You probably want something like `ggplot(data=dados, aes_string(x = input$candidato)) +  geom_bar(stat="count")`. Don't uses `$` inside `aes`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is very hard to understand Your question, actually You should explain it more briefly...

While looking at Your code, i can straight tell You that the problem is this part of code:

```
aes(x=dados[input$candidato])
```

You havent defined well if `input$candidato` should filter out the rows or columns....

I assume You meant columns, then the code should look like that:

```
 aes(x=dados[, input$candidato])
```

Comment: Not only is this not the correct way of using `ggplot`, but data.frames can indeed be indexed on columns by using `df[i]` notation because they are `list`s.

Comment: @Malvina_a sorry for the misspecified question. But you send me the right message. Works!